# Custom cite command doesn't print external period

Tags: biblatex, citing

I am using a custom command for which I've previously received help here (I am still a newbie).
While using the `cite:ibid macro`, this command seems to have some kind of problem with periods being added outside of the parentheses.

If I write `\parencitearticle{source}`, it correctly yields `(Ibid.)`

On the other hand, if I write `\parencitearticle{source}.`, it still yields `(Ibid.)`, instead of `(Ibid.).`

As you can see in the screenshot, this problem seems to occur only with periods, so using other punctuation marks doesn't yield wrong results. I have tried fixing it by myself, but I can't possibly do it without your help.

This is my code in its entirety:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt,twoside]{report}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\usepackage[german, main=italian, english]{babel}

\usepackage[autostyle]{csquotes}
\setquotestyle{english}
\MakeOuterQuote{"}

\usepackage[
  backend=biber,
  style=authoryear-icomp,
  maxbibnames=4, maxcitenames=2,
  ibidpage=true, pagetracker=false,
  dashed=true,
  autolang=other,
]{biblatex}

\DeclareCiteCommand{\parencitearticle}
  {\booltrue{citetracker}%
   \booltrue{pagetracker}%
   }
  {\ifthenelse{\ifciteibid\AND\NOT\iffirstonpage}
     {(\usebibmacro{cite:ibid})}
     {(\printtext[bibhyperref]{\printfield{title}}%
      \setunit{\addcomma\space}%
      \printfield{journaltitle}%
      \setunit{\addcolon\addspace}%
      \printfield{pages})}}
  {\multicitedelim}
  {\usebibmacro{postnote}}


\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage[colorlinks=true, linkcolor=blue, urlcolor=blue, citecolor=blue]{hyperref}

\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@suppperiodical{carolina-spartan,
  author = "Anon.",
  journal = "The Carolina Spartan",
  month = "5",
  url = "https://chroniclingamerica.loc.gov/lccn/sn83025802/1856-05-29/ed-1/seq-2/",
  number = "14",
  pages = "2",
  title = "Brooks and Sumner",
  volume = "XIII",
  year = "1856",
}
\end{filecontents}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}



\begin{document}

\noindent
\parencitearticle{carolina-spartan}
\\
The following are the ibid results:
\\
\parencitearticle{carolina-spartan}
\\
\parencitearticle{carolina-spartan}.
\\
\parencitearticle{carolina-spartan}..
\\
\parencitearticle{carolina-spartan}:
\\
\parencitearticle{carolina-spartan};
    
    
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: The problem might be that you add the parentheses manually by inserting them directly. That could confuse the punctuation buffer which already has set a dot and don't want to double it. I'm not sure if that's the reason and can't test it right now. But try to remove the manually set parentheses and add `[mkbibparens]` after `{parencitearticle}`.

Comment: `[\mkbibparens]` with backslash. Sorry for the typo.

Comment: Thank you! It now works flawlessly!

Comment: @lukeflo Would you like to type up an answer here (that can be accepted) so that the question can be marked as resolved?

Comment: @moewe of course. Done!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments, the problem were the manually inserted parentheses *inside* the cite command definition. That doesn't work properly with the punctuation buffer.

The correct way is to insert `\mkbibparens` as optional argument of the command definition:

```latex
\DeclareCiteCommand{\parencitearticle}[\mkbibparens]
  {\booltrue{citetracker}%
   \booltrue{pagetracker}%
   }  
  {\ifthenelse{\ifciteibid\AND\NOT\iffirstonpage}
     {\usebibmacro{cite:ibid}}
     {\printtext[bibhyperref]{\printfield{title}}%
      \setunit{\addcomma\space}%
      \printfield{journaltitle}%
      \setunit{\addcolon\addspace}%
      \printfield{pages}}}
  {\multicitedelim}
  {\usebibmacro{postnote}}
```